# python slice set in list

Tags: python, list, set, slice

i would like to slice a set within a list, but every time i do so, i get an empty list in return.

what i try to accomplish (maybe there is an easier way):

- i got a list of sets
- each set has 5 items
- i would like to compare a new set against the list (if the set already exists in the list)
- the first and the last item in the set is irrelevant for the comparison, so only the positions 2-4 are valid for the search of already existing sets

here is my code:

```
result_set = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']

result_matrix = []

result_matrix.append(result_set)
```

slicing the set is no problem:

```
print result_set[1:4]

['2', '3', '4']

print result_matrix[:][1:4]

[]
```

i would expect:

```
[['2', '3', '4']]
```

Comment: Did you mean `result_matrix[0][1:4]` instead of `result_matrix[:][1:4]`?  OR `result_matrix.extend(result_set)` instead of `result_matrix.append(result_set)`?

Comment: the issue is that result_matrix[:] == result matrix. result_matrix has only one result set in it, the 0th one. You're asking it for the 1st result set through the 4th result set, which is an empty set.

Comment: I feel a sense of duty to point this out: `result_set` is a list, not a set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want to do:

```
>>> target_set = ['2', '3', '4']
>>> any([l for l in result_matrix if target_set == l[1:-1]])
True
>>> target_set = ['1', '2', '3']
>>> any([l for l in result_matrix if target_set == l[1:-1]])
False
```

Generalising and making that a function:

```
def is_set_in_matrix(target_set, matrix):
    return any(True for l in matrix if list(target_set) == l[1:-1])

>>> result_matrix = [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']]
>>> is_set_in_matrix(['1', '2', '3'], result_matrix)
False
>>> is_set_in_matrix(['2', '3', '4'], result_matrix)
True
# a quirk - it also works with strings...`
>>> s = '234'
>>> is_set_in_matrix(s, result_matrix)
True
```

Note that I have used `l[1:-1]` to ignore the first and last elements of the "set" in the comparison. This is more flexible should you ever need sets of different lengths.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what i needed. I altered just this: any([l for l in result_matrix if target_set **[1:-1]** == l[1:-1]])

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> result_set = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']

>>> print result_set[1:4]
['2', '3', '4']

>>> result_matrix.append(result_set[1:4])
>>> result_matrix
[['2', '3', '4']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `result_matrix[:]` returns the whole matrix as it is. You need to treat the result you want as a part of the array.

```
>>> result_matrix.append(result_set)
>>> result_matrix[:]
[['1', '2', '3', '4']]
>>> result_matrix[:][0]
['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> result_matrix[0][1:4]
['2', '3', '4']
```

Also, as pointed out by falsetru:

```
>>> result_matrix.extend(result_set)
>>> result_matrix
['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> result_matrix[1:4]
['2', '3', '4']
```